# Why can't I change anything in hook_node_view_alter?

Tags: 7, hooks

I'm trying to change one of the side panels, no clue what is rendering it but it displays a list of OG members.

Anyways, in `template_block_view` and `hook_page_alter`, the widget has already been rendered into HTML. The only place I've been able to find where its still in pre-render form is `hook_node_view_alter` but no matter what I do to the `$build` variable, it has precisely 0 effect on anything (yes, I made sure the function is being called).

So if its not to change the view, what is `hook_node_view_alter` for? This is on drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

`hook_node_view` and `hook_node_view_alter` are only going to give you control over the inner content of a particular `$node` that you may be viewing. Such as the inner content when going to www.mysite/node/2

Now if you have additional "blocks" or maybe as you called them "side panels", these are not a part of the `$node` array and thus cannot be changed in hook_node_view or alter. If the side panel is indeed a block, then you can change it's output with [`hook_block_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7.x) and `hook_block_view_alter`. Among other things depending on what you are trying to do. The process is to find the block ID, and target it inside your hook. However I may be wrong, because it really depends on what the block is.

You will need to provide a printscreen showing exactly what you are talking about if we are going to figure out the right direction you should take on altering it.

I would suggest downloading the "[devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel)" module, enabling it, then look at the ouptut from `hook_block_view_alter` and see if it's what you're looking for.

```
function mymodule_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
  dpm($block); //make sure the module devel is installed and enabled for this function
}
```